# Weird variable behaviour PHP

Tags: php

This little piece of code isn't behaving as I would expect it to:

```
$flash_messages = $_SESSION['flash'];

$_SESSION['flash'] = array();

return $flash_messages;
```

I am wanting `$flash_messages` to have the saved values of the `$_SESSION` variable. But when I change the `$_SESSION` to a blank array, flash messages is also returned as a blank array. What is going on?

Comment: i hope you are using session_start() at first.

Comment: [This works](http://codepad.org/CY8Iv5Ai).

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$_SESSION` before assigning it to `$flash_messages` to ensure, it holds the values your are looking for?

Comment: Can you check http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php#85448

Comment: You probably have run the page twice already and `$_SESSION['flash']` is already an empty array.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `$_SESSION['flash']` has a value in it other than a blank array?

Comment: Are you using a custom session handler using `session_set_save_handler()` or the PHP `SessionHandler` class?

Comment: Hmm, it was because get_flash was called after the action was completed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but check your `register_global` value in php.ini

Comment: It should not be that as the index value for $_SESSION would have to be 'flash_messages' for that to occur, or vice versa.